# Не получается получить значение ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, объекты

Есть объект `$_product` при выводе которого
`var_dump($_product);` получаем

```
"Джемobject(WC_Product_Simple)#7990 (11) { ["id"]=> int(2922) ["post_content"]=> string(1140) "Джемo -это...}"
```

Если же я пытаюсь вывести значение одного из элементов, например `var_dump($_product->post_content);` или echo `$_product->post_content;`, то получаю `string(0) "`

В чем я ошибся?

Answer (score 2):

Вы же сами говорите, что есть объект. Вероятно, у него есть свои методы для вывода. Вот, первый результат гугл-поиска: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Simple.html

Comment: но среди перечня функций я к сожалению не вижу вывода описания

Comment: Я понимаю, что вы уже разобрались, но я всё таки отвечу. У данного класса всего 4 метода и сразу бросается в глаза метод get_title() и если поглядеть его, то сразу всё понятно: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Simple.html#55-70

Answer (score 0):

Удалось. правильный ответ: `echo $_product->post->post_content;`